# how can i change a cell value depending on what another says?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I thought the IF function could help but I'm not having luck with this particular issue:

- in column A, I have written several letters including "N"
- in column B, I have random numbers and same for column C
- so for every row, every time the cell in column A has an "N", I want to copy to column D the value of column B, but for any other letter I want to copy the value in column C.

Here's what I've tried: =IF((A1="N"), B1,C1)

Thank you for any help that you can give me.

Comment: apologies, I'll edit that ASAP

Comment: In what way(s) does this produce an undesired outcome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like column A contains more than just the letter `N`, so you can use `ISNUMBER` and `FIND`:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("N",A1)),B1,C1)
```